# Angular directives that call methods on child directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, parent-child

I am looking for advice on how to implement a hierarchical structure in Angular, where a directive (`<partition>`) can call a method on a child directive's controller (`<property-value>`).

I have put together a detailed example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/95kjjxkh/1/

As you can see, my code contains an outer directive, `<partition>`, which displays one or more `<property-value>` directives within.

The `<property-value>` directive offers an editing method, `editItem()`, which allows the user to change the value of a single entry. (To keep my example short, I simply assign a random number here, but in my production app, a modal will appear, to query the user for a new value.)

This works fine. However, in the outer directive, `<partition>`, I would like to add the ability to create a new, blank `<property-value>` directive and then immediately call its editing method so that the user can enter an initial value. If no initial value is entered, the new item would be discarded.

I have seen examples of inner directives calling methods on enclosing directives, but not the other way around.

Is there a way to do this? Alternatively, is there a better way for me to build this kind of view?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use $broadcast to talk both ways. To your parent as well as to your childrens.

Answer (score 0):

In your Child controller you can do the following

```
  app.directive('propertyValue', function() {
return {
    require : '^partition'
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        item: '='
    },
```

with this you will get the parent controller in child directive's link function like this

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs,partitionCtrl){
  partitionCtrl.getChildCtrl(element)
  }
```

in partition controller create getChildCtrl function and with that call "propertyvalue" controller function

```
 controller: function ($scope, ItemFactory) {
 // your code
var propValueCtrl =undefined;
 this.getChildCtrl =function(elem)
 {
   propValueCtrl = elem.controller();
 }
 this.callChildFunction = function()
 {
    propValueCtrl.Edit();// whatever is the name of function
 }
```

call this function when needed in property link function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't quite work in practice. I've integrated your code into a new Plunkr and have added comments (app.js: lines 52-61) to explain why this isn't ideal: http://plnkr.co/edit/hHACVtZVxchkAopRKdhP?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted the plnkr.co link and can't edit my comment above. Here's the same code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z72pb6wc/

Comment: the *easiest* way to ensure that the directive is drawn before the child function is called is to wrap the call to the child function in a `$timeout`.  https://jsfiddle.net/huvfyvhs/